# SOAP API is failing with 404 for gateway endpoint

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to run my JMeter test pointing to API gateway endpoint. Test fails with 404, direct endpoint works fine.I have added the HTTP header with 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' in JMeter

On hitting the request via SOAP UI with API gateway. It works fine.

Comment: any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that it’s helpful to others, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add in Header Manager:

- Content-Type = text/xml or something similar

An additional requirement might be to add a SOAPAction header.

Look at Soap UI http logs to see what headers are sent.

Another option is to start recorder and set JMeter as a proxy in Soap UI:

- Proxy host: localhost
- Proxy port: 8888

Answer (score 0):

As you said that your endpoint directly works fine, run it and check both request/response, if there are any additional headers/parameters that needs to be sent along with the request, make sure you are adding in your jmeter request.
P.S: If your endpoint works fine then it will work with jmeter too..!!